# How to run a function when a key is pressed?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been searching on how to do it without pygame, but I haven't found a way.

Basically all I want to do is to press a key and play a sound, but I do not know how to register keystrokes in python.

edit: Forgot to mention, for Windows.

Comment: As I've stated in the original comment, I would like a way without pygame.

Comment: is this in the shell? or in a gui?

Comment: It's in pycharm

Answer (score 0):

It (getting keypresses and playing sounds) is probably operating system specific, and you might want to use some widget toolkit (interfaced to Python). So consider using one of [PyGTK](http://pygtk.org/), [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro), [PySDL2](https://pypi.org/project/PySDL2/) or some other suitable toolkit. I guess that for a game, PySDL2 should be the most suitable.

You might focus on the WinAPI only and follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/342740/841108).